# Magento 2 How to get Product details in CMS block using product id or SKU?

Tags: magento2, product, cms-block, sku

How to get product details in CMS Block using product Id or SKU in Magento 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a custom Widget](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-magento-2-widget/) and let widget field have an option called product Id, get the product Id into your template and display the details in the with widget .phtml.

You can add that widget into your cms static block.

We have a possibility to load product by creating custom module and pass the variables like this `{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Customproductload" product_id="1" template="Vendor_Module::customproductload.phtml"}}`

Comment: yes, But here I have two blocks are loading 2 products each , The details and design of each block products are different so we can not use widget per this scenario.How to load two products in each block using sku like rendering products of a particular category using cat_id. ?

Comment: You can easily load products by id's even there are two products. Just add the product id or sku's as comma seperated in the widget field and render accordingly.

Comment: We have a possibility to load product by creating custom module and pass the variables like this {{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Customproductload" product_id="1"template="Vendor_Module::customproductload.phtml"}}

Comment: ok, can we create two different widgets for two blocks for product rendering.But both widgets phtml is same right..?How can we differentiate in phtml for different styles.And second comment can i put more product id's by comma separate..?

Comment: Yes use two different templates and change styles/design classes accordingly. Yes We can pass multiple parameters like product_id_two="1"

Comment: yes, created custom module and template file but how to get product id in template file from cms block.Can we get it in phtml like echo $this->getProductIdTwo(); like this..?

Comment: Yes, please take reference link . Just concept from m1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573472/display-product-id-in-static-block-magento